# Copy sheet from another spreadsheet to other spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello I am trying to solve a problem with copying a sheet.

Do someone any solution for this, or another way for copy sheet?

Here is  short description when it fails:

Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id "(here is ID of spreadsheet where is the sheet for copy)".
at myFunction(test copy by ID:14:30)

```
function myFunction() {
  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("someID");
var NazevTpm = "TPM 11.08.2023 - RSA2"
var strojName = "TPM-RSA02"
var listTPMID = "someID";

ss.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.openById(listTPMID)).setName(NazevTpm);

}
```

It's interesting that my script sometimes runs without fails and sometimes i recieve only fail

thanx for any help

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("someID");
  var NazevTpm = "TPM 11.08.2023 - RSA2"
  ss.copy(NazevTpm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the issue you mention is caused by the *spreadsheet* rather than the script. There are many things that can slow down a spreadsheet. To improve spreadsheet performance, see these [optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339).

There is no `Spreadsheet.copyTo()` method. Use [Sheet.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet), like this:

```
function copySheetToAnotherSpreadsheet() {
  const sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('some spreadsheet ID').getSheetByName('TPM-RSA02');
  const targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('another spreadsheet ID');
  const targetSheetName = 'TPM 11.08.2023 - RSA2'
  sourceSheet.copyTo(targetSpreadsheet).setName(targetSheetName);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for answer, i forgot to add getSheetByName to my example of skript, but standart script looks like this, but still not working.

I have try to use your method, but i received the same fail

Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id "Source SpreadsheetID".

Comment: Now i have tried with another source spreadsheet and everything works. Do you have any idea where could be problem with specific spreadsheet?

Comment: Is it possible that the problem could be in size of source Spreadsheet? Spreadsheet has 427MB

Comment: It is indeed likely that the issue is not with the script but with the _spreadsheet_. To improve spreadsheet performance, see these [optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339).